# Turn columns into a dictionary with python

Tags: python

I have exported some data into a text file to contain two columns of data, like so:

```
a   b

c   d

e    f

g  h
```

Unfortunately, the columns are not evenly spaced. a and b might be separated by 2 blank spaces, while c and d might be separated by 5 blank spaces, while e and f might be separated by 3 blank spaces, etc.

How can I take these columns and create a simple dictionary like {a:b, c:d, e:f, g:h} ?

Comment: do all columns contain only two words?

Comment: Welcome to the site: you may want to read [help/on-topic], [ask] and [mcve], and re-word your question accordingly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try this:

```
f = [i.strip('\n').split() for i in open('filename.txt')]

final_dict = {i[0]:i[1] for i in f}
```

By default, the split function will automatically divide the line at the instance of spaces, no matter what the length.

Comment: @Marcus glad to help! Please consider accepting this answer, as it is beneficial to the StackOverflow community. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

You can set a custom `delim_whitespace` parameter to `True` in the [`pandas.read_table`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.20/generated/pandas.read_table.html) function:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_table('data.txt', delim_whitespace=True)

d = {a: b for a, b in df.values}
```

Answer (score 2):

What about a simple solution like this?

```
d = {}

for line in open('file.txt'):
    [key, value] = line.split() # split() without arguments splits by whitespace
    d[key] = value

print(d)
```